# How to pass an additional parameter to passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware

(I already do `fbStrategy.passReqToCallback = true` ) I am riffing off 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-linking-all-accounts-together but want to use this social authentication service for multiple apps, ex: the one that controls the heating system, the one that turns on the sprinklers etc.

Basically if one of these apps checks with the server and doesn't have a correct token it get redirected to this social authentication service (social-auth). When the user presses on of the social login buttons it grabs the parameter of what app its arriving from and adds it as a parameter for `/auth/facebook/:appid`

```
    // send to facebook to do the authentication
    app.get('/auth/facebook/:appId', function(req,res,next){
        passport.authenticate(
            'facebook', { scope : 'email' }
        )(req,res,next);
    });
```

`req` of `req,res,next` is the serialized user record. At this point social-auth doesn't know who the user is.

```
fbStrategy.passReqToCallback = true;  
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fbStrategy,
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        var email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase()     
        process.nextTick(function() {...
```

Once authorization is complete I want to redirect back to the calling app and I need the `:appId` param to ride along so I can go back to the right site.

Now generally it would work if I just made a variable like `currentAppId` accessible to the various social stategies but If you happened to have multiple people authenticating at the same time then you conceivably have a user return to the wrong app, or some other users app. That's why I need `appId` to travel as param to `passport.authenticate` . Where should I be looking to figure out how. Could I wrap `passport.authenticate` or otherwise modify things?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the request itself to transfer some additional parameters from and to the strategy function. In the following example the two parameters `_toParam` and `_fromParam` are used for this concern.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/:appId', function(req,res,next){
    req._toParam = 'Hello';
    passport.authenticate(
        'facebook', { scope : 'email' }
    )(req,res,next);
})


fbStrategy.passReqToCallback = true;  
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fbStrategy,
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(req._toParam);
        req._fromParam = 'Hello 2';
        var email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase()     
    process.nextTick(function() {...
```

If you need to store the id for further requests, you could use a map with the socket of the current request as key.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much. I tried to figure out your last suggestion with searches like 'express middleware socket of the current request' but didn't really find anything. Any references would be appreciated

Comment: Actually it didn't work

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fbStrategy,
            function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(req._toParam);

comes back as undefined even though it is defined here..

    app.get('/auth/facebook/:appId', function(req,res,next){
      req._toParam=req.params.appId
      console.log(req._toParam)            

I was reading the wrong log.

Comment: For all the social auth strategies the req gets replaced by req.user

Comment: @Manfred Steiner I have a question about this. why do you need to pass (req,res,next) at the end of the function? Is it anonymous? When you redirect you just need passport.authenticate("facebookStrategy"), function(req, req){} ... and you don't need to pass the parameters again. What is the difference?

Comment: Do you know how to get this working after the new rules of twitter https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342 I used to pass the query item but now I cant

Comment: i would recommend to add state in : { scope : 'email' , state : "You stringyfied data" } and then access state from req.query.state in callback

Answer (score 2):

In my case, due to the authentication flow, to set up a variable in `req` was not working.

The second option, set `passReqToCallBack: true` was giving me many issues, so it was not an option either. [More information can be found here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/421).

The solution came to me following the answer that [Dhiraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4746878/dhiraj-katekar) posted in thread above, I did set a single string in the `state` and I was able to use the string on the callbacks.

```js
login: (req, res, next) => passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    state: req.query.username
  }, () => next())(req, res, next),

  onSuccess: async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.state)
  },
```